# Hook For GoLang Android

Tags: android, go, hook, reverse-engineering

I'm searching for hook, in golang android, like for c++ binaries in android we have frida hooking framework and several plthook available publicly,

is there hooking framework or something similar available for golang binaries in android?

like in frida we want to hook system of libc then

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName('libc.so', 'system'), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
        console.log('[+] system called with command:', Memory.readUtf8String(args[0]));
    },
});
```

I just need any similar hooking for golang like if I want to hook

```
time.Now()
```

function in golang binary which will be available in exports of the binary then how can I without actual function formatting from ida etc..